# How to create correctly a generic model mapper based on the code I wrote?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create a generic model mapper using [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/). This is what I got till now, it has only one method, that converts to the type given as second parameter

```
@Component
public class Mapper {
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    public Mapper(ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    public Object convertToType(Object object, Class<?> type) {
        Object convertedObject = modelMapper.map(object, type);
        return convertedObject;
    }
}
```

And this is how I use it:
`DepartmentDTO departmentDTO = (DepartmentDTO) modelMapper.convertToType(department.get(), DepartmentDTO.class);`, here I convert from a department entity to it's DTO class
And here I make the opposite, from DTO to entity.
`Department department = (Department) modelMapper.convertToType(departmentDTO, Department.class);`

**EDIT**
How can I improve my code? Is it something wrong about the method I use?

Comment: What is the **actual** question? What is the actual **problem** you are facing? `How to create correctly a generic model mapper?` is way too broad to answer.

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation but my question is how I can improve my code to make it correct. Right now I think that using this syntax to convert my converteted departmentDTO into department using cast is wrong `Department department = (Department) modelMapper.convertToType(departmentDTO, Department.class);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid casting, use a generic method.

```
public class Mapper {

    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;
    
    //ctor

    public <R> R convertToType(Object source, Class<R> resultClass) {
        return modelMapper.map(source, resultClass);
    }
}
```

Additionally you can change method parameters names to something more descriptive of their functions - `source` and `resultClass` are just some possibilities.